# Combining three data sets from different files

Tags: excel, vba

I have three files A.csv, B.xls, and C.xls which are all in the same directory

I would like to take the 7 left most columns from each file ignoring the top header row, but taking all other rows and put them below each other in one sheet (combined sheet) using VBA.

In Sheet1 I have added the file names to the files in cells C3 to C5, and the directory path in C1.

The name of the activeworkbook is Book2.xlsm

Below is the code I have used so far to try and achieve this:

```
Sub combineSheets()

    Dim directory As String, fileName As String

    Dim fileRng As Range
    Dim fileCell As Range

    directory = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value

    Set fileRng As Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")
    Set fileRng As Range(fileRng,fileRng.End(xlDown))

    For Each fileCell in fileRng 
          fileName = fileCell.Value

         'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

          Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

          Workbooks(fileName).Select
          Sheet1.Select
          Range("A2").Select
          Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(Selection.End(xlDown).Row - 2, 7)).Select
          'need code to work out how to add on the bottom
          Selection.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets("combined").Range("A2")

         'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Next

    Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheet1.Select

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, good effort - just a couple of syntax issues. I've re-structured your example to be a bit more efficient, you can step through the code using F8 to see what it's doing.

Also, based on your example I'm assuming that your data doesn't have an blank rows in it, if it does then you will need to use something like Range("A" &  Rows.Count).End(xlUp) instead.

Try this:
(with a couple of extra notes)

```
Sub combineSheets()

    Dim fileName As Range

    '// Use 'As' to dimension (Dim) something, use '=' to Set something.
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    '// Loop through the filenames
    For Each fileName In Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Cells

        '// Open workbook with value in C1 and filename
        Workbooks.Open Range("C1").Value & fileName.Value

            '// Copy to first workbook
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1
                .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 7)).Copy Destination:= _
                WB.Sheets("combined").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            End With

        '// Copy finished so close workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    '// Go to next filename
    Next fileName

'// Re-activate first workbook
WB.Activate

'// Release WB object from memory (note the '=')
Set WB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response....I tried running through it using F8, and the csv file is opened but it seems to be stopping at  `With ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1`...The csv file sheet name is not Sheet1, but I didn't think it mattered..., and I get a run time error 348 object doesnt support this property or method...

Comment: That would be a syntax error on my part. Oops! - Try replacing that line with:

`With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

Comment: Now getting an runtime error 1004 on the two lines below, I think it might be due to the fact that the for the first copy and paste, the `WB.Sheets("combined").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` might push it past the last row of the entire sheet, since there is no data in it yet...however would probably work once some data is in it...

Comment: You are indeed correct! Try this instead:

`WB.Sheets("combined").Range("A" & WB.Sheets("combined").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Instead of going from A2 Down, it goes from A1048576 Up, which if there's not data it will hit A1, and the Offset function will shift it down to A2 :)